# windows forms application does not starting on an other mashine

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I use the Microsoft.Win32 namespace in my windows forms application.
I install my application on an other mashine and it does not starting.
If this namespace was deleted from my application, the application will starting.

why?

Thanks the help, and sorry my english :)

My app:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;


    RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        disableTM();
        disableBTN.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void enableBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        enableTM();
        enableBTN.Enabled = false;
        disableBTN.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void disableBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        disableTM();
        disableBTN.Enabled = false;
        enableBTN.Enabled = true;
    }




    private void disableTM()
    {
        try
        {
            key.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", 1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void enableTM()
    {
        try
        {
            Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any errors or exceptions?

Comment: Also try looking in the event log.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a look at [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Your question contains no details and is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem root is accessing `Registry`, to diagnose, first comment the lines which are using `Registry` , if the problem solved, the problem is caused form access permission, uncomment the codes, right click on your app and `run it as administrator`